# Recover data from .mdf file, and no correct version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I have an `80gb` `.mdf` file that I need to open and get the data out of.

It was on a computer running `SQL Server 2008 R2 Express` that died, but I was able to pull the file off the half dead `HDD`. I don't know how this file passed the `10gb` limit imposed by the express edition of `SQL Server`, but it did.

So far I've installed trial versions of `SQL Server 2008` and `SQL Server 2012`, but I was not able to attach the `.mdf` file to either instances.

Does anyone know where I can find a copy of `2008R2`? Microsoft provides downloads for the other two versions, but I cannot find an `R2` version anywhere.

Alternatively, is there another, better, way to get the data out of this database?

I have the log file as well.

---

**Edit:**

I have a full version of `SQL Server 2012`. Run 2012 Management studio as administrator and when I run this:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Orange] ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Orange.mdf'),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Orange.ldf')
FOR ATTACH
GO
```

I get:

```
Converting database 'Orange' from version 661 to the current version 706.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 661 to version 668.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 668 to version 669.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 669 to version 670.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 670 to version 671.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 671 to version 672.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 672 to version 673.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 673 to version 674.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 674 to version 675.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 675 to version 676.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 676 to version 677.
Database 'Orange' running the upgrade step from version 677 to version 679.
Msg 5570, Level 23, State 3, Line 1
FILESTREAM Failed to find the garbage collection table.
```

It created the database (shows up in Management studio) and now says "Recovery Pending".

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? You will not be able to attach a 2008 R2 database to 2008. You can only attach to 2008 R2 or newer. I don't know that you'll be able to find 2008 R2 today from any official/legal channels unless you have access to an MSDN subscription, but this will not work *any better* than 2012, so let's try and figure out why the file can't be attached there. There's a chance it was corrupted during the failure and that's the end of it (this is why storing proper backups, on a separate physical disk, is important).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks Aaron. I added an edit.

Comment: The error I get in 2012 is: `FILESTREAM Failed to find the garbage collection table.`

Comment: So sounds like the database has some FILESTREAM going on, did you enable this feature on the 2012 instance?

Comment: Yep, I enabled FILESTREAM. I actually just found a VHD file from Microsoft that contains a trial version of `SQL Server 2008R2 Standard` and I was able to restore the database! I'll now see if I can export chunks of data out, so that they can be opened in a more modern version.

Comment: Download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26113